# How to analyze impact of a query on another queries?

Tags: mysql, performance

Suppose I have two tables let's call them `values` and `candlesticks`. I can compute candlesticks over values using three different methods:

- In trigger before inserting new value with `insert on duplicate key update`
- Periodically issue `insert into candlesticks ... select from values`.
- Using some service written in some language that would periodically poll `values`, computing updating or adding new candlesticks.

I'd like to analyze how this methods would impact queries to both `values` and `candlesticks`. The best thing I came up so far is to write a script that would put new `values` and another one which would issue two typical queries (one for `candlesticks` and one for `values`) and use `performance_schema` as it described in [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/performance-schema-query-profiling.html) to gather data about queries and plot it.

Which seems like a problem that should be solved already by some tool. Is there a such tool (free) that can monitor some query performance over time? Maybe there are some other approaches to the problem?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a such tool that can monitor some query performance over
>   time?

There are several solutions such as Spotlight, SolorWinds, SQL Monitor (Red Gate).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've edited the question. I need a free tool, not a paid one. And for mysql (seems like `SolorWinds` is MS SQL server only)

Answer (score 0):

If you have good indexes *and* you are doing less than, say, 100 queries per second, the impact is low enough that your question does not matter.

Otherwise, please provide specifics -- `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the queries, inside transactions where relevant.  Clarify things: "periodically" = once an hour? once per millisecond?  "Poll" == read the entire table?  If so, how big is the table?

The existing profiling tools tend to say that all the time is spent "sending data", which is not a useful clue.

I like to use the slowlog with `long_query_time = 1`.  After a day, summarize with `pt-query-digest`.  That will say which query is the "worst".  Focusing on that one will (often) make a big difference in overall performance.

**More**

How can one measure the presence/absence of an index?  Measure the difference between spinning drive vs SSD?  Those tend to have far more impact on performance than a competing thread that may or may not ask for the CPU or I/O or a mutex at about the same time.

I don't think there is any useful data in performance_schema that would differentiate a `TRIGGER's` impact.

The Slowlog helps identify the "worst" queries, but gives no clues of why they are "bad".

Capturing and graphing trends in the slowlog -- some of this is available in various tools, such as Monyog and MEM.

Comment: Periodically means once a second or so. I could provide more specific information about tables and so on, but that's not the point. The point is how can I measure impact that different things have on a database. So far seems like there's no good way of doing that.

Comment: @user1685095 - I added to my Answer.